# VueJS : scrollBehavior not working correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I see an error in my console when I use this function in my vuejs router.

```js
    export default new Router({
      mode: 'history',
      routes: [
        {
          path: '/',
          name: 'Root',
          component: ListProject
        }
,
        {
          path: '/theme/:slug/:id',
          name: 'Thematic',
          component: Thematic,
        }
      ],
      scrollBehavior() {
        return { x: 0, y: 0 }
      }  
    })
```

In my case, I would like to go back to the top of the page every time we go to a new page

**Error**

```
element.geometry is undefined
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Can you please share more of you code, like where are you calling scrollBehavior?

Comment: Aren't you by default sent to the top of the page when changing the route? That should be standard. Can you maybe replicate this issue in a codepen or similar?

Comment: It works without problem yes, but it gives me an error in the console that does not block the script

Comment: But what happens if you remove all this custom scrollBehavior? It should by default scroll to the top when changing route